# Install Ubuntu in local server

Tags: localhost, ubuntu

My goal is to install Magento2 on a computer running Ubuntu which will be a server for my local network, so various workstations can access and build products.
I have a computer that meets the requirements, and it has a new hardrive with a fresh install of Ubuntu.
I have tried to follow various guides i have found online to do this, but it seems they are all out of date in one step or another (i have refor.ated and reinstalled Ubuntu after each failer to make sure i start fresh each time)
I am hoping someone can point me in the write direction for a guide/video to follow that is up to date, and specificly for creating it as a localhost (using apache2, mariadb, and php7.2).
While linux is fairly new to me, i am computer literate but still having a tough time.

Comment: please go thorugh this https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/UbuntuServer_HowTo.html

Comment: This seems outdated but ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

By guides are you referring to `docker` or similar virtualisation technologies ? If not, that might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: To make it more clear what I am looking for, I have made the below list:
1) Have a computer with a fresh install of the latest version of Ubuntu
2) Need to set it up as a localhost on our internal network, so we can use our workstations to connect to the Magento2 installation, and play around with it
3) I would like to use the most up to date versions of MySQL or MariaDB, PHP, and Magento2 Community edition
4) Need a guide/tutorial/video to set up MySQL/MariaDB
5) Need a guide/tutorial/video to set up PHP
6) installing Magento2 (either using the GUI/Install Wizard, or via the Console).